# Integral sign produces error if AMS theorems module is'nt used

Tags: errors, lyx, amsthm, tufte-book

I have a document in LyX Tufte-book class with the following preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} % for colour
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{caption}

% add numbers to chapters, sections, subsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\definecolor{oucrimsonred}{rgb}{0.6, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{persianred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.2, 0.2}
\definecolor{persimmon}{rgb}{0.93, 0.35, 0.0}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{oucrimsonred}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{oucrimsonred}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\itshape\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
  {2pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\leavevmode\newline}% before the title body
  [{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]% after the title body

% section format
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\LARGE\itshape\color{persianred}}% format applied to label+text
  {\vspace{2em}\llap{\colorbox{persianred}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

% subsection format
\titleformat{\subsection}%
  {\normalfont\large\itshape\color{persimmon}}% format applied to label+text
  {\llap{\colorbox{persimmon}{\parbox{1cm}{\hfill\color{white}\thesubsection}}}}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\def\mathnote#1{%
  \tag*{\rlap{\hspace\marginparsep\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
  \footnotesize#1}}}}
}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
\newcommand{\nth}{n^\text{th}}
\addtolength{\jot}{1em}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2.2em plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro \normalsize {%
 \setlength\abovedisplayskip{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}%
 \setlength\belowdisplayskip{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now, if I have an integral sign in the document, errors are produced, which goes away if I use one of tge AMS theorem module. I don't to use those modules now. What's causing the clash?

[image]

Comment: It is probably related to the settings at `Document->Settings->Math Options`, can you describe what do you have there?

Comment: The problem is with the physics package. If you use an integral sign lyx loads the package `esint` before the user's preamble, and this package should be loaded after `amsmath` if both are loaded. Since the physics package loads `amsmath` you get the error. For some reason LyX's AMS theorem modules loads `amsmath`, but I think this is by mistake, since `amsmath` is not required for `amsthm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `physics` package. If you use an integral sign in the document LyX loads the package `esint` before the user's preamble, and this package should be loaded after `amsmath` if both are loaded. Since the physics package loads `amsmath` you get the error. For some reason LyX's AMS theorem modules loads `amsmath`, but I think this is by mistake, since `amsmath` is not required for amsthm`.

To fix the problem, the best way to make sure `amsmath` is loaded first in LyX is to set `amsmath` to be loaded always in `Document->settings->Math Options`.

Comment: Thank you! Oh where would I be without you!

Comment: @kobaltishblue_312, glad to help :)